# How to get transaction history of ERC-721 token in Solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-721, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to figure out how to get a history of values for a specific ERC721 token of known contract address.

I want to do some maths in solidity and do not want to do all that in web2; therefore, I want to get the transaction history of the token within solidity.

Is there a way to do this? I know that [Moralis](https://deep-index.moralis.io/api-docs/#/token/getWalletTokenIdTransfers) has an API that does the same, but I want this in my smart contract.

Cheers!

Ankesh S

Comment: You can get the transaction history from etherscan api too

Comment: I don't need API, I want to have it built into the smart contract.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store all that info inside the contract? Storage is pretty expensive

Comment: No, I don't want to store info in a smart contract, I just want to fetch the already stored information.

The transactions history is already there in the Ethereum blockchain, I just want to fetch that information,

Answer (score 0):

You can write a new `event` containing the transaction data you want and emit it within the `_transfer` function. You can query for these events on the frontend.

Comment: He actually said he did not want to do this outside of the contract.

Comment: @Itération122442 It sounds like he wants to avoid storing extra info on-chain, yet avoid fetching all the transactions using the frontend. To my knowledge, this is not possible. Transaction history is not stored in a single data structure that can just be retrieved. Transactions are spread over different blocks. He'll either have to use my solution or store extra data on-chain.